# Stencil: Sudden build error without message after adding `@Method` to component

Tags: stenciljs, stencil-component, stencil-compiler

I cannot give too much information here (because there really isn't), but only this:

All of the sudden, **after adding a `@Method` function to a stencil component**:

```js
@Method()
async setMenuItems(items: Element[]): Promise<void> {
  // code here
}
```

**the component stopped compiling with the following - really unhelpful - error**:

```sh
[ ERROR ]  ./src/components/menu-content/menu-content.tsx:63:44
           build error

     L62:  @Method()
     L63:  async setMenuItems(elements: Element[]): Promise<void> {
     L64:    const unsupportedChildren = elements.filter(e => !this.isSupportedChild(e)).map(e => e.tagName);

[12:37.1]  build failed in 7.02 s
```

### Things to notice

- the return type `Promise<void>` inside the error-message is highlighted red
- there are other `@Method`s that do work within this component (even with the same return type).
- the "broken" `@Method` is structurally equal to those that do work.
- TypeScript compiler does not complain about anything
- Only stencil compiler fails

### I already tried...

- to google for this issue - did not find any hints to this problem
- to remove the `async` and add `return Promise.resolve()`
- to rename the method (I mean.. why not)
- to move the method to another place in class
- to remove the whole method (compiles fine x( )
- to remove the `@Method` decorator (compiled, but of course my method is removed from API)
- to delete `node_modules` folder and reinstall

I remember that I already had this error once, and apparently I somehow fixed it (or not, idk). But if I did, I cannot remember how.

Does anyone have an idea how to debug this - or even better fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. A more complete version of my component is:

```js
import { Element, ... } from '@stencil/core';

class MenuContent {
  @Element() element: MenuContentElement;

  @Method()
  setMenuItems(elements: Element[]): Promise<void> {
    // ------------------^^^^^^^
    // Element is meant to be the built-in browser interface for Element
    // but stencil thinks that this is the imported Element from '@stencil/core'!
  }
}
```

The exact problem here is, that the stencil-compiler seems to assume that the `elements` parameter is of type `Element` that is imported from `@stencil/core` which is obviously wrong and leads to this strange unhelpful error.

### Possible Solutions

#### 1. Use an alias type for the built-in `Element` type

```js
// types.ts
export type DomElement = Element;

// menu-content.tsx
import { DomElement } from './types';
...
async setMenuItems(elements: DomElement[]): Promise<void> { ... }
```

#### 2. Switch to `HTMLElement`

**Note: This is only legit, when you don't need to support other Element-types such as `SVGElement`s for example!**

```js
async setMenuItems(elements: HTMLElement[]): Promise<void> { ... }
```

#### 3. Use alias in import statement

**Please note:** When using @stencil eslint rules, they will complain about your renamed import and say that "own class members are not allowed to be public".

I created a ticket for it here: https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-eslint/issues/28

```js
import { Element as ElementDecorator} from '@stencil/core';

class MenuContent {
  // eslint will complain about that:
  // "Own class properties cannot be public."
  @ElementDecorator() element: HTMLMenuContentElement;
}
```

Comment: You could also alias it in the import:
`import { Element as ElementDecorator } from '@stencil/core';` and use it as `@ElementDecorator()`.

Comment: That's right, will update my answer. But note that the `eslint` rules does not like that and will give you a warning that own class member are not allowed to be public.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue not with the `Element` type but with the `Event` type, so it appears to be rooted deeper - also about a year after you reported this issue it seems to still be a problem with Stencil

Comment: Have a look at my answer below :) I think you're experiencing the same issue as I did. When you import `Event` from stencil, in your class whereever you mention `Event`, it refers to stencil's decorator - not the built-in HTML interface as you want to. This is a classic case of name-clashing. To fix, just rename your import: `import { Event as StencilEvent } from '@stencil/core'` and then use the renamed decorator `@StencilEvent() myEvent`, and use the HTML event type as usual `myHandler(event: Event)`. See point 3 of my answer for reference.